# Ordering Growth Functions

Tags: time-complexity

List the following growth functions in the order from the most efficient to the most complex:

1. nlog<sup>2</sup>(n)+n<sup>2</sup>
2. n<sup>2</sup>-nlog(n)
3. nlog(n)
4. n<sup>2</sup>log(n)
5. 2<sup>n</sup>+100n<sup>4</sup>
6. n<sup>3</sup>-100n<sup>2</sup>

I understand that the function is deemed most efficient or most complex by the overpowering function of n.  However, I am unsure as to how to proceed when there is multiple references of log.

I know (5) is the most complex as it has an exponential n and will increase, well, exponentially.  (6) follows behind in complexity because it is polynomial.

Now comes my confusion.  I would think (1) would come before 6, as its value of n<sup>2</sup> is added to the log function.  Then (2) as the log function is subtracted.  Then (4) as it is multiplied.  This leaves 3 as most efficient with a double logarithmic.

My guess, most efficient to most complex:
3
4
2
1
6
5
Is this anywhere near correct or am I out in left field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remeber that log(n)<sup>a</sup> ∈ O(n) for all `a`. You can use that to put all the given functions into polynomial/exponential categories:

1. n<sup>2</sup> + n•log<sup>2</sup>(n) ∈ **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**
2. n<sup>2</sup> ­− n•log(n) ∈ **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**
3. n•log(n) ∈ **O(n•log(n))** <strike>∈ O(n<sup>2</sup>)</strike>
4. n<sup>2</sup>•log(n) ∈ **O(n<sup>2</sup>•log(n))** <strike>∈ O(n<sup>3</sup>)</strike>
5. 100n<sup>4</sup> + 2<sup>n</sup> ∈ **O(2<sup>n</sup>)**
6. n<sup>3</sup> − 100n<sup>2</sup> ∈ **O(n<sup>3</sup>)**

Now you know that {1,2,3} < {4,6} < 5.

Inside **{1,2,3}**, `n•log(n)` is the smallest, since it is `< n^2`. and obviously `n^2 - x` < `n^2 + y`, so 2 is smaller than 1.

Inside **{4,6}**, `n^2•log(n) = n•n•log(n) < n•n•(n-100) = n^3-100n^2`, since `log(n) < n-100` for big n.

So the correct order is 3 < 2 < 1 < 4 < 6 < 5.

Answer (score 0):

Just always try to find the fastest growing function: the order is n^n >> n! >> a^n >> n^a >> n*log(n) >> n >> log(n) >> log(log(n)). If you multiply these functions, it is the same n*log(n)*log(n) grow faster than n n*log(n), therefore the order is: nlog(n) < n^2-nlog(n) < nlog^2(n) + n^2 < n^2log(n) < n^-100n^2. Although I would say thay n^2-nlog(n) is similar to nlog^2(n) + n^2) since the fastest growing is n^2 so actually the logs are not interesting.